# Is there is a tool for documenting java application?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there is a tool for documenting the java application. I mean if I want to specify each function and each variable in my code what should it take and what its type(int,double,...etc)... how can i do that? I want it to be in a separated file(a tool generate a file in such format(ex. .chm))... This thing is available in .net and there is a tool that can do this for you(sand castle)... I hope that there is a tool in java that can do similar job like this....

Thanks a lot.

**Thanks Guys for ur help... it was really useful, i'm using right now javadoc... it's awesome, Thanks for all of ur recommendation ;)**

Comment: Im using it right now, thanks ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is, check out Javadoc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

You probably have everything necessary already installed. If you're using Eclipse, you can generate the documentation in html format right from your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities are e.g. [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) and [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Answer (score 2):

How  about [javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html)?

The documentation of your project would look like the [Java API](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) is a tool for generating API documentation in HTML format from doc comments in source code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try javadoc